# want to remove gap in between two label controls

Tags: css, sass

Hi there I have just created a rating control using half stars with fontawesome the problem is a gap in between each half star. I use overflow hidden on the star container like this. [codepen](https://codepen.io/kirkdm/pen/ZyGRmM) the gap is visible in chrome

```
label:nth-child(4n+2) {
  width: 12px;
  position: relative;    
  display: block;
  margin-right: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

label:nth-child(4n+4)::before {
  content: '\f006';
  display: block;
  width: 11px;    
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

How can I have the stars more closely joined so there isn't a gap

Comment: seems to work if you remove `overflow: hidden` from `label:nth-child(4n+2)`

Comment: Yeah it does I hope there is no more hicups with this controls styling thankyou @MichaelCoker

Answer (score 0):

You can change the margin on the class

```
.rating label:nth-child(4n+2)
{
margin-right: 0px;
}
```

once you do this the stars come together, then you can change the width of the right column to make it a little larger (if you want)

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't render properly on my chrome browser, it still has the gap when viewing it

Comment: Yeah I don't know why that is but my chrome still shows me a gap unfortunately

Comment: Is it zoomed in maybe? If not then someone else might find a solution for you :-)